# Problem with enumerate and compactenum

Tags: numbering, enumerate, enumitem, alphabet

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{enumitem}    
\usepackage{enumerate}    
\usepackage{paralist} 

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]    
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{enumerate}

\begin{compactenum}[label=(\alph*)]    
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{compactenum}    
\end{document}
```

seems that the `enumitem` and `enumerate` and `paralist` contradict each other...

What can I do to get alphabet numbering with `compactenum`...

Comment: Replace `\begin{compactenum}[label=(\alph*)]` with `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), nosep]` and don't load `enumerate`: `enumitem` can do everything it does.

Comment: Why are you using `enumitem`? The answer to the second question is to replace `[label=(\alph*)]` with `[(a)]` in your enumeration environments; is `enumitem` necessary or was it an attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: @Bernard with those changes the document does not compile for me.

Comment: There's also a problem with `paralist`. `Enumitem` can also have all of its functionalities, so you should also remove it.

Comment: the **[label=(\alph*)]** command will not work without **enumitem** package!!!!!!!!! and without **paralist** the **compactenum** command will not work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to define your customized list as a `paralist`'s `compactenum` variation using the `nolistsep` key:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{enumitem}    

\newlist{compactenum}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[compactenum,1]{nolistsep}

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]    
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{enumerate}

\begin{compactenum}[label=(\alph*)]    
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{compactenum}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The label can be made global:

```
\setlist[compactenum,1]{nolistsep,label=(\alph*)}
```

and then just

```
\begin{compactenum}
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{compactenum}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only `enumitem`, you can now just add the option `nosep`, i.e.

```
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, label=(\alph*)]    
\item an apple    
\item a banana    
\item a carrot    
\item a durian    
\end{enumerate}
```

The option `nolistsep` from Gonzalo Medina's answer is now deprecated (see [documentation](https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)).