# enumitem's resume but using compactenum

Tags: enumitem, incompatibility, paralist

I'd like to combine the functionality of `paralist`, namely the `compactenum` environment, and those of `enumitem`, namely `[resume]`.

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}
\item One.
\item Two.
\end{compactenum}
But integers don't stop at Two!
\begin{compactenum}[resume]
\item Three.
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

but this is what I get

[image]

Comment: First of why do you think functionallity from enumitem can be applied to stuff from paralist? Is that documented somewhere? If now how can that be an incompatibility? I'd say that anything from paralist can be done using enumitem only

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235054